# Microsecond thread sleep

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, sleep

I need to give a PWM output through a special output on my machine. I was just wondering how I could achieve something similar to thread.sleep but with the resolution of microseconds?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Only attempt this if this is a synchronous serial interface, one where you also generate the clock signal.  SPI is very common.  If it is asynchronous then you *must* use hardware support.  Exposed in .NET by the SerialPort class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to rely on a so short period of time. You should bear in mind that the accuracy at these intervals is not too good and is even conditioned even by the CPU of the given machine. Thus, in any case you should thoroughly test the given approach under the given conditions to make sure that it delivers exactly what you want.

The smallest time value supported by .NET is a `Tick` (one hundred nanoseconds, as explained in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)) and thus you can build your own "sleep method" dealing with microseconds. Sample code:

```
 Dim count As Integer = 0
 Dim sw As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch
 Dim microSeconds As Integer = 5
 sw.Start()
 Do While (sw.ElapsedTicks < 10 * microSeconds)
 Loop
 sw.Stop()
```

Comment: I think that in the same documentation you provided http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx Clearly states: "A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second". So,  1 tick = 100 nanoseconds?

Comment: I was just saying, that in the documentation YOU provided, it says, "A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds", I wasn't trying to start some kind of insult war, "A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds" means that A Single (1) Tick represents one hundred (100) nanoseconds. -> You will be correct if it said One hundredth which is 1/100. And in the same documentation: "The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals" which says that the tick counts every 100 nanoseconds?

Comment: @RdPC well... It seems like I was the one misunderstanding here. I didn't have any doubt that my code was right and didn't realise that what code shows is 100 nanoseconds precisely. I got completely lost in the conversation, sorry.

Comment: @RdPC you surely were helpful. There is no justification for my attitude (= plainly not considering what you were saying). Actually, I have done this in the past various times (although exceptionally) here in SO (getting involved in a discussion where I wasn't even getting the point of the other person; or intending to defend what is clearly wrong, like now). This is not my attitude in general (I look forward to the right result not to being right/wrong) but I guess that some days I am just too tired and forget that discussion/confrontation is what SO (and myself) is about. Sorry again.

Comment: @RdPC PS: bear in mind that I find pretty annoying the attitude of certain persons not intending to help, but just to show I am not sure what... I like SO quite a lot and the general attitude of people here; but there are quite a few persons like the aforementioned ones who are really tiring to deal with (proposing crazy things in some cases with no true relation with what the given question/answer is about). I am a pretty open-minded person but am starting to have some "light prejudices" in SO. Situations like this one help me to remember that having prejudices (even light ones) is bad.

Comment: @RdPC I have paid your favour back by correcting one of your previous answers (you have to release the objects by, at least, making them null when dealing with Office interop. Well... Nothing in VB.NET) and only because you are a "paisano" :)

Comment: It's for PWM so I need it to be pretty accurate down to 100 microseconds. Otherwise, it wont work.

Comment: @user2005848 as said, when dealing with so short intervals everything matters (the cpu has to be able to perform the actions as quickly as required, time requirements of each single line of code has to be brought into picture, etc.). 100 micros sounds close enough to a value which can accurately be dealt with (1 millis) but you have to test the approach by bearing all this in mind to make sure.